# React-admin redirection and props

Tags: redirect, react-admin

I'm using React Admin userRedirect hook and I'm redirection to a "page" that is a components. Is there a way to pass data to the page/component that I redirect to?
I tried this and observe the following.

The page I'm redirecting to:

```
const PublicPage = (props) => {
    console.log('data: ' + props.data);

    return(
        <Card>
        <Title title="Public Page" />
        <CardContent>
            This is a public page. + {props.data}
        </CardContent>
    </Card>
    )
}
```

If I do: redirect('/public', {data:'this is some data'}), the console log displays 'data: undefined' and no data is displayed.

Is this something doable with RA? Thanks for any suggestion you may have.

Christian

Answer (score 3):

You could redirect to a location with a query string (e.g. '/public?foo=bar') and read that query string from your PublicPage component.

Alternately, you can use the location *state* - some sort of data container provided by react-router. This isn't supported by `useRedirect`, but it's not hard to do by hand:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const useRedirectToPageWithState = () => {
   const history = useHistory();
   return useCallback((pathname, state) => {
      history.push({
          pathname,
          state
      })
   }, [history]);
}
```

Then in your PublicPage component, you can read the location state using [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation):

```js
const PublicPage = () => {
    const { state: data } = useLocation();
    // now data contains what you passed to the page
```

Comment: Thanks François. The second approach seems a bit more secure to me as data is not traveling through URLs. Maybe a nice feature to add to react-admin? Christian